# Connecting to Azure DevOps Git from Visual Studio 2022 Empties Solution Explorer

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2022

I've used Azure DevOps TFS for years. I'm trying to tackle switching to Azure DevOps Git. So far...not so good. I'm hoping someone can spot the error of my ways and point me in the right direction. All of this is using Visual Studio 2022.

Step 1: Create a new Project in Azure DevOps called "GitTest"

Step 2: Create a new Umbraco site in Visual Studio called "GitTest"

Step 3: Using Team Explorer in Visual Studio connect to the "GitTest" project in DevOps from Step 1.

As soon as I complete Step 3, my solution explorer is blank.

Here's my Solution Explorer before Step 3:

[image]

Here's my Solution Explorer after Step 3:

[image]

In case you're wondering here's what my screen for Step 3 looks like:

[image]

Comment: Test the same steps in VS2022 version 17.6.5, it shows the Azure DevOps repo folder after connecting the Azure Repo. Can you share the VS 2022 version? And what is your expected result(Show local repo or Azure DevOps repo after connecting to Azure DevOps)?

Comment: On the other hand, you can also check if the clone process has completed after connecting to Azure DevOps. If the clone step is still in process, the solution explorer will show blank page

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I'm on version 17.7.5  I hadn't yet triggered a clone.  All I did was connect to to the Azure DevOps project and it wiped out everything in my Solution Explorer.  I'm new to using Git so I don't know if this is user error, or something is wonky between ADO and VS22.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT My expected result is that my Solution Explorer will show all of the files/folders in my project even after I connect to Azure DevOps. Note I've waited 30+ mins and the Solution Explorer still has not populated.

Comment: Please refer to the answer below. I can reproduce the same issue in VS2022. And find the method to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue. When I connect to Azure DevOps Service without cloning the repo, the Solution Explorer will show blank page.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to set the option: **Close open solutions not under Git when opening a repository** to **No** in **Git -> Settings -> Git Global Settings**.

[image]

Then it will keep the solution after connect to Azure DevOps.

Comment: Many thanks @KevinLu-MSFT!!